# AVCam memory low warning

Tags: xcode, didreceivememorywarning, avcam

This is less a question and more a record of what I've found around the AVCam sample code provided by Apple for iOS4 and 5 camera manipulation. The symptoms of the problem for me were that my app would crash on launching the AVCamViewController after taking around 5-10 photos.

I ran the app through the memory leak profiler and there were no apparent leaks but on inspection with the Activity Monitor I discovered that something called mediaserverd was increasing by 17Mb every time the camera was launched and when it reached ~100Mb the app crashed with multiple low memory warnings.

Comment: Thanks! Please split the answer into a answer, that you can then accept: [Etiquette for answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) and [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to)

Comment: Tried that but because I'm not a premium user it wouldn't let me answer my own question within 24 hours... didn't have time to mess around with it (or forget what I wanted to record)... I'll see if I can do it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple revised the sample code on Oct 17 2013, fixing the retain cycle. The issue is due to a improper usage of `self` within the blocks defined in the `init`.

Here's the revision description

> Fixed retain cycles in `AVCaptureManager` that result in leaks. *NOTE* - if you've adapted `AVCam` code in your app, you should adopt the fixes made here in `AVCaptureManager.m`'s `init` method. Without these fixes, you may be leaking `AVCaptureManager` instances and leaving the camera running constantly while your app is in the foreground.

---

**However**, the fix they introduced only works in case of Manual Retain Count. If you are using ARC on the project, apart from getting rid of `release`/`retain` calls and other obvious things, the storage qualifier for `weakSelf` has to be changed from `__block` to `__weak`, like follows.

```
__weak AVCamCaptureManager *weakSelf = self;
```

In fact the semantic of `__block` changed with ARC. In MRC it caused the variable to be weakly referenced, wheres in ARC it does not and `__weak` must be used for this purpose.

More information about this topic can be found here: [How do I avoid capturing self in blocks when implementing an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api)

Using the new `init` implementation from the last revision and using `__weak` instead of `__block`, finally caused the `dealloc` method to be properly called.

---

Finally, for those who hate to carry around old legacy code, here's a modernized version of the `AVCam` project: https://github.com/Gabro/AVCam

Features:

- memory leaks free
- uses ARC
- modern Objective-C syntax
- minor UI fixes for iOS 7

Comment: Hi Gabriele, I've had a look at your AVCam project. You might change the 'ARC compatible' comment to 'ARC exclusive'? I've added it to my non-ARC project and there are some compile failures relating to use of ARC exclusive functionality.

Comment: @RedNightingale Absolutely, terrible choice of words indeed. By the way you can selectively enable ARC on specific files even in a non-ARC project, if you like. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll look into that. Have tried out the new revisions of the Apple code and they seem to be finally working properly so I'll promote this to be the answer.

Comment: If you can, use Gabriele's AVCam code.  If you're editing an earlier version of AVCam in an existing project, be sure modify your init method to use weakSelf everywhere you need to.  If you're still having problems, start checking retainCounts for self at the end of the init method.  If you're seeing retainCounts that don't make sense, you missed converting something to use weakSelf.

Comment: definitely still a memory leak running the Apple demo on iOS 9, these updates still fix it

Answer (score 16):

First thing I did was put logging into the dealloc methods of all the AVCam files. I quickly discovered that the AVCamCaptureManager and AVCamRecorder weren't being deallocated when the AVCamViewController was. I checked out the retain and release calls and they appeared to balance so I put a breakpoint on the [captureManager release] and discovered that it had a retainCount of 2 AFTER the release (and hence the AVCamCaptureManager dealloc wasn't being called).

Next I stepped through the creation process for the capture manager and discovered that it had a retain count of 3 immediately after the init method was called.

Stepping through the init method and checking the retain count on every line I discovered the following two lines were both incrementing the retain count:

```
[self setDeviceConnectedObserver=[notificationCenter addObserverForName:AVCaptureDeviceWasConnectedNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:deviceConnectedBlock]];
[self setDeviceDisconnectedObserver=[notificationCenter addObserverForName:AVCaptureDeviceWasDisconnectedNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:deviceDisconnectedBlock]];
```

Looking through I found that the removeObserver counterparts were INSIDE the dealloc method of the AVCamCaptureManager (which wasn't being called) and so the retain count never dropped to 0.

To fix it I created a new public removeObservers method:

```
 -(void)removeObservers {
     NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
     [notificationCenter removeObserver:[self deviceConnectedObserver]];
     [notificationCenter removeObserver:[self deviceConnectedObserver]];
 }
```

and taking the same lines OUT of the AVCamCaptureManager dealloc method.

Calling [captureManager removeObservers]; and THEN calling [captureManager release]; in the AVCamViewController dealloc method successfully drops the retain count to 0.

Testing with the Activity Monitor now has the mediaserverd process humming at only 5-17Mb and the crashing stops!

Hope this helps anyone else having this problem!

Comment: Better... the mighty SO gods have allowed me to answer my own question now ;)

Comment: The mighty SO gods have allowed me to say thanks by giving it my +1 ;)

Comment: Good description. I believe we hit this same problem.

Comment: brilliant, if i could buy you a beer online i would!

Comment: @RedNightngale Hi I just ran into this issue and I believe a less hacky solution is finally available. Check my answer out ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this problem recently. I found that the real root problem was that deviceConnectedBlock and deviceDisconnectedBlock were implicitly referring to self, leading to retain cycles. To fix it, change all the ivar references in those blocks to use weakSelf.

This way, you won't need to remember to call a teardown method explicitly.

Hope this helps someone else.

REF: [View controller dealloc not called when using NSNotificationCenter code block method with ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699118/view-controller-dealloc-not-called-when-using-nsnotificationcenter-code-block-me)

Comment: I did have one reference to self in the block. I replaced that with weakSelf and reverted to the 'normal' AVCAM release code. The CaptureManager is still not calling dealloc. The article you linked to refers to __weak for the reference however this is only applicable to ARC code (which I'm currently not using). I need to use __block instead but don't understand enough about 'blocks' to be able to come up with an equivalent solution that works.