# What's the executive order of block as function argument in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

As apple's documentation says,

> "Blocks are also used for callbacks, defining the code to be executed when a task completes."

So block should execute after the body of the function in which the block is passed executes. But I wrote the following test code:

```
void testBlock(void(^test)()){
    NSLog(@"1");
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        testBlock(^{
            NSLog(@"2");
        });
    }
}
```

and the output is only "1".
So where's the `NSLog(@"2")`?

@Julian Król
But look at this function in AFNetworking:

```
- (void)setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                          failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
// completionBlock is manually nilled out in AFURLConnectionOperation to break the retain cycle.
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-retain-cycles"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu"
self.completionBlock = ^{
    if (self.completionGroup) {
        dispatch_group_enter(self.completionGroup);
    }

    dispatch_async(http_request_operation_processing_queue(), ^{
        if (self.error) {
            if (failure) {
                dispatch_group_async(self.completionGroup ?: http_request_operation_completion_group(), self.completionQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    failure(self, self.error);
                });
            }
        } else {
            id responseObject = self.responseObject;
            if (self.error) {
                if (failure) {
                    dispatch_group_async(self.completionGroup ?: http_request_operation_completion_group(), self.completionQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        failure(self, self.error);
                    });
                }
            } else {
                if (success) {
                    dispatch_group_async(self.completionGroup ?: http_request_operation_completion_group(), self.completionQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        success(self, responseObject);
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        if (self.completionGroup) {
            dispatch_group_leave(self.completionGroup);
        }
    });
};
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
```

This function doesn't explicitly call the block and the block parameter doesn't even has a name so it seems that the block should not be executed. But as I use this function as following:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/rss+xml"];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSXMLParser *XMLParser = (NSXMLParser *)responseObject;
    [self.parserDictionary setObject:XMLParser forKey:urlString];
    [XMLParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
    XMLParser.delegate = self;
    [XMLParser parse];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //When an error occurs while parsing.
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Loading Data"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.tableView animated:YES];

}];
```

And the block is truly executed. What's is the reason here?

Comment: the problem with blocks you have is that you are mixing when you are passing a block and the function calling that block. In the example from afnetworking you see the implementation of a function for which you implement the block that it will execute inside. You would have to look at those methods implementation details to see where those blogs are called.

Comment: I read the article and I can tell the function and the block apart but here in this AFNetworking function the passed in block doesn't even has a name, how can the function call the block?

Comment: the function in the definition gives a name to each attribute so to know how to refer to this :)

Comment: Ah so in the parameter list, success and failure are the names of block? I only know I can name a block variable with `void (^success)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)`...

Comment: yes success :) when there is a method signature in the implementation file it has a name for the attribute to have the way to reference to the attribute in the function body

Comment: In short method getting block as an attribute decides whether and when to call a passed block

Comment: Okay thx I get it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not call passed block inside this is why you have on the output only NSLog(@"2");

You should have something like this:

```
void testBlock(void(^test)()){
    NSLog(@"1");
    test();
};
```

You should also check whether passed block is a nil (as calling it in case it is nil will crash)

Comment: Ah so the executive order of block is set by me, not necessarily executed after the body of the function?

Comment: If you place the block before the log this is how it will be executed. Yes you are defining the order as long as you do it synchronously. In the example I posted it will be printed 1 and then 2.

Comment: Thx but see my newly-edited answer and I'm still puzzled here.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-objective-c-blocks--mobile-14319 maybe this will helps you more especially second part of the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can think of blocks as chunks of code that can be passed around like variables. You call a block like a function so in your case you would do something like `!test ?: test();` This is semantically equivalent to:

```
if (test != nil) {
    test();
}
```

You may find the following example useful:

```
// Define block that returns void and takes void arguments
typedef void (^MyBlock)(void);
// Define block that takes two ints and returns an int
typedef int (^AddBlock)(int a, int b);

@interface MyClass : NSObject

// NOTE: You have to COPY the block variables.
@property (copy) MyBlock blockOne;
@property (copy) AddBlock blockTwo;

@end

@implementation ...

- (void)runBlocks
{
    !self.blockOne ?: self.blockOne();
    if (self.blockTwo != nil) {
        int sum = self.blockTwo(1, 2);
    }
}

@end
```

> function in AFNetworking:

A couple of things:

1) You should not have a failure and a success block. Instead define one block like this:

```
typdef void (^CompletionHandler)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id responseObj, NSError *error);
```

Then when you implement the block you can check for an error like so:

```
...^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id responseObj, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // Handle the error
    } else {
        // YAY everything went well
    }
}];
```

2) You are ignoring retain cycles here which is NOT a good thing to do. Instead you should define a weak version of `self` that you can reference in the block like so:

```
__weak __block MyClass *welf = self;
myBlock = ^{
   welf.coolProperty = coolValue;
};
```

Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773342/what-is-the-difference-between-a-weak-and-a-block-reference) for info on `__weak` and `__block`

Comment: Thx but I want to know the executive order of block.

Comment: Do you mean the order in which the blocks are called? That all depends on how you call them and if you're using concurrency. e.g. `test(); NSLog(@"1");` will produce `"2,1"` and `NSLog(@"1"); test();` will produce `"1,2"`

Comment: Exactly the order. Yeah now I understand this and please look at my newly-edited question.

Comment: @Ceasar I edited my answer to include some things about the code in your edited answer. I hope you've got what you need now.

Comment: "You are ignoring retain cycles here which is NOT a good thing to do." No he is not. What makes you think there may be a retain cycle here?

Comment: `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-retain-cycles"` and the fact that he is referencing `self` in a block that is owned by `self` which means that `self` owns `self`. Standard ingredients for a retain cycle.

Comment: You mean using typedef then use `CompletionHandler success, failure;` instead to simplify the code? Thx and I'll notice the second one.

Comment: @Caesar not necessarily `typedef` but you should have only one block with an error argument that you check first.

Comment: Not completely understood for the method `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:Failure:` truly needs 2 blocks which has same type of arguments.