# What does __weak it mean exactly?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am (trying to) learn `Objective-C` and I keep coming across a phrase like:

```
__weak IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *webViewLeftConstraint;
```

What does `__weak` it mean exactly in `Objective-C`?
Why we need to put `__`(underscore twice) in variable?
Can we use only one time? like( _ ) other declaration in other language..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773342/what-is-the-difference-between-a-weak-and-a-block-reference

Comment: .. or you could take a look at the Wikipedia article on "weak reference".

Answer (score 1):

If the outlet is referencing a UI Object in the `View` hierarchy then you should make it `weak` as the view hierarchy already has a `strong` reference.

`Weak` is specifically needed to avoid a retain cycle.