# Pausing AVPlayer at a given CMTime

Tags: objective-c, ios, avplayer

I'm writing an app for iOS 4.3 and above and using `automatic reference counting`.  I have a video which is played using an `AVPlayer` and would like to be able to pause this video when a given `CMTime` is reached.  I am currently using `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes` and pausing the `AVPlayer` inside the `block` which is called.  It works but I receive the error:

```
Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle
```

My code:

```
timeObserver = [player addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:endTime //An array of one NSValue representing a CMTime
                                                 queue:NULL 
                                            usingBlock:^{
                                                            [player pause];
                                                        }];
```

I can't work out the correct way of doing this and would be very grateful for any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the __weak storage decorator.
e.g. put this before your block code:

```
__weak MYClass* blockSelf = self;
```

and use blockSelf instead of self inside your block.

**Update**
Just found this excellent answer here on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854315/100848

Comment: Thanks weichsel.  I'm not sure your answer would work in my case... Can I use __weak with iOS 4.3?  Anyway that is covered in the link  you provided so thank you!