# In iOS4, having an NSTimer running with an NSRunLoop disables Touch/Gesture Input

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

This is a followup from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129632/erratic-behavior-with-nstimers-and-nsrunloops) (which was resolved beautifully by Michael Frederick).

I am currently debugging between a iOS5 device and an iOS4 device. Essentially I have a UIImage which is animating a swipe to instruct the user to swipe to continue. The animation code is as follows:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {
self.finger.alpha = 1.0; 
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
CGAffineTransform originalTransform = self.finger.transform;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^ {

    self.finger.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-200, 0);
    self.finger.alpha = 0.0;

    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        self.finger.transform = originalTransform;
        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(repeatSwipeAnimation1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        self.swipeTimerForFinger1 = timer;
        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runLoop addTimer:self.swipeTimerForFinger1 forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [self.swipeTimerForFinger1 fire];


        }];

    }];
```

and the timer selector:

```
-(void)repeatSwipeAnimation1 {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^ {
    self.finger.alpha = 1.0;
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    CGAffineTransform originalTransform = self.finger.transform;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^ {
        self.finger.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-200, 0);
        self.finger.alpha = 0.0;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.finger.transform = originalTransform;

    }];
}];
}
```

This works completely fine. However, on iOS4, swipe gestures seem to be disabled; I am unable to swipe to continue as I am able to on iOS5. The only theory I have is that having the timer run on the main thread somehow disables the gesture recognizer (which I presume is sensing touch on the main thread as well). My only issue is that I have attempted to put this animation in the background as follows:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {
            self.finger.alpha = 1.0; 
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
               CGAffineTransform originalTransform = self.finger.transform;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^ {

                self.finger.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-200, 0);
                self.finger.alpha = 0.0;

            }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                self.finger.transform = originalTransform;

                 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(goToNewThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];                    

            }];

        }];
```

and the new thread selector:

```
-(void)goToNewThread {

     NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(repeatSwipeAnimation1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    self.swipeTimerForFinger1 = timer;
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.swipeTimerForFinger1 forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    [self.swipeTimerForFinger1 fire];


    [pool release];


}
```

The animation is in place, but yet again, it seems to disable any swipe gesture recognition. I have mulled over SO, my O'Reilly materials, and the Apple documentation and have not been able to find a solution. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried the `UIView` animation option `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`?

Comment: NJones! Thank you! That did the trick! Though, a quick question, is there anyway to have multiple options while doing the animation?

Comment: Glad to help. Yes you can use more than one. I have added an answer to show how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the formality out of the way; You need to add `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` to the options in your animation block.

To answer your comment question. Yes you can rather easily use more than one animation option. You generally use the bitwise or operator "`|`", like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations...
```

Answer (score 0):

NJones had the correct answer. I simply needed to add `UiViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` under the options of my `[UIView animationWithDuration...]` code.