# Do Objective-C blocks capture the property value or the object value?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Let's suppose I have an instance `anInstance` of some class that has a property `aProperty`.  When I use `anInstance.aProperty` inside a block, does the block capture the (pointer) value of `anInstance` and then send the `aProperty` message to that captured (pointer) value or does the block only capture the value of `anInstance.aProperty`?

Comment: It keeps the instance.

You can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The block will capture `anInstance` here. Remember that property accesses are just message sends.

If you think about it as `[anInstance aProperty]` it may be more obvious. But to note, `anInstance->someIvar` still captures `anInstance` and not the iVar.

Comment: That's definitely the behavior I'd expected, but some strange errors I was seeing (related to CoreData, managed object contexts, and persistent stores) led me to wonder whether I might have misunderstood or if the compiler might be doing something different/tricky because of the dot notation.