# MagicalRecord save causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, exc-bad-access, magicalrecord

I am having issues when I try to do "save" with MagicalRecord. My code:

```
- (void) findInternetObject {
    [InternetObjectFinder runBlockSuccess:^(NSManagedObject *obj) {
        obj.attr1 = @"abc";
        [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveErrorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
               NSLog(@"failed to save attr1, Error: %@, %@", error.localizedDescription, error.userInfo);
        }];
    }];
}
```

where obj was created in method "runBlockSuccess" method in "InternetObjectFinder" class:

```
InternetObject *obj = [InternetObject MR_createEntity];
```

The app crashes at line:

[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveErrorHandler

with error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a scope issue inside your nested blocks,
have you tried to write something like this (not tested):

```
- (void) findInternetObject {
    NSManagedObjectContext *defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
    [InternetObjectFinder runBlockSuccess:^(NSManagedObject *obj) {
        obj.attr1 = @"abc";
        [defaultContext MR_saveErrorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
               NSLog(@"failed to save attr1, Error: %@, %@", error.localizedDescription, error.userInfo);
        }];
    }];
}
```

If the proble persist maybe this detailed answer can help you:

> [How do I avoid capturing self in blocks when implementing an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api)

Answer (score 0):

You should call save method on main thread. Your code looks that you are saving core data into block. If that doesn't work you can use below code to save.

```
MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if(success){
        NSLog(@"success");
    }
}];
```