# iOS Blocks - use of undeclared identifier self

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, block

I am new to blocks. I am inside a singleton and I do this

```
void (^ myBlock)() = ^(){ [self doStuff]; };
```

I receive this error **use of undeclared identifier self.**

doStuff is a method inside the singleton.

but if this block is declared inside another method, Xcode is OK.

Why is that? thanks.

Comment: where are you writing this line??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define the block in your interface and initialize in any of your methods (including initializers ) in your @implementation file like below:

```
@interface YourClass {
   void (^ myBlock)();
}

@implementation YourClass

  - (void)yourMethod {
    myBlock = ^(){ [self doStuff]; };
  }


@end
```

Comment: it should work then .. if you are defining the block as i have mentioned above .. it should work .

Comment: ah, you probably mean void (^ myBlock)(); inside the interface and myBlock = ^(){ [self doStuff]; }; inside a method....

Comment: unless you're using ARC, you need to copy the block

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call `self` directly in a block.
Rather you should make a safe block-pointer from `self` and access it inside your block.

```
__block id safeBlockSelf = self;
void (^ myBlock)() = ^(){ [safeBlockSelf doSomething]; };
```

See [How do I avoid capturing self in blocks when implementing an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7853915/856880) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**because every method gets passed self as a hidden param.** self is a variable like any other and the block can 'see it/capture it' if in the method

if it is not in a method, self is not a variable set anywhere and the block cant 'see it'