# ios: self becomes nil in block?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, null, self

I have a view controller, which calls several async network ops (I am using AFNetworking), and handles the response using blocks.
Consistently - one of the blocks shows me that self == nil, but other blocks in the SAME view controller, using the same underlying AFNetworking client, show me that self != nil and behave as expected.

Why does this particular block gives me a nil self reference? Am I doing anything wrong? I tried googling for this symptom, in vain.

My View controller is compiled with ARC, testing on iOS 6.1 simulator...

Comment: Add code snippets of the blocks please

Comment: Sounds as if there was an inconsistent `weak` vs. `strong` usage - but then again, without the code this is just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing self directly, you should access it indirectly, from a reference that will not be retained. [for more..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api)