# NSMutableArray doesn't get XML values

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml, tbxml

I am trying to parse an XML file with `TBXML` and put the values into a multidimensional `NSMutableArray`
but the problem is that the values don't get added into the array, if I output the values then it returns `null` and `0`.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self downloadAndParseXml:@"http://www.w3schools.com/XML/note.xml"];

    // RETURNS 0
    NSLog(@"weatherArray count: %d", [weatherArray count]);

    // RETURNS NULL
    NSLog(@"weatherArray value: %@", weatherArray[0][0]);
}

- (void)downloadAndParseXml:(NSString *)xmlUrl
{
    // Allocating the array
    weatherArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    TBXMLSuccessBlock sBlock = ^(TBXML *tbxmlDocument) {
        if (tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement)
            [self fillArrayWithXmlContents:tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement];
    };

    TBXMLFailureBlock fBlock = ^(TBXML *tbxmlDocument, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failureblock: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    };

    [TBXML newTBXMLWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:xmlUrl] success:sBlock failure:fBlock];
}

- (void)fillArrayWithXmlContents:(TBXMLElement *)element {
    do {
        if (element->firstChild)
            [self fillArrayWithXmlContents:element->firstChild];

        if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"note"]) {

            // Adding values into the multidimensional array
            [weatherArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                [TBXML textForElement:[TBXML childElementNamed:@"to" parentElement:element]],
                [TBXML textForElement:[TBXML childElementNamed:@"from" parentElement:element]],
                [TBXML textForElement:[TBXML childElementNamed:@"heading" parentElement:element]],
                [TBXML textForElement:[TBXML childElementNamed:@"body" parentElement:element]], NULL]];

            // Correct value is getting logged
            NSLog(@"weatherArray value: %@", weatherArray[0][0]);
        }
    } while ((element = element->nextSibling));
}
```

Comment: what does tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement prints?

Comment: if I use `NSLog` the whole XML document is getting printed with the correct values

Comment: is ur class ARC enabled?

Comment: @iOSCoder Yes it is, by the way the values DO get logged when I `NSLog` it inside the `do while` loop

Comment: feels like some issue with the thread..as ur using blocks...

Comment: where ur printing the arrayvalues after u add those objects?

Comment: i think you're right about the thread-blocks issue, how to fix that issue?

Comment: I want to get the same values outside the method, if I print it outside that method (after its execution) then I get `null`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you need to do is wait for the process to get completed and the block literally doesn't know what your doing inside it or i would say the inside function is not been captured by the block.so use the array(call the function which is using your array) only after block gets completed.

Example:

```
TBXMLSuccessBlock s = ^(TBXML *tbxml) {
    NSLog(@"yes");
    // Do something with TBXML object "tbxml/add it ur array
   //Here you call the function which is about to use your array.

};

//Not outside the block.
```

**EDIT** : Refer this==> [How do I avoid capturing self in blocks when implementing an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api/7854315#7854315)

Comment: Thank you very much, This is the solution I need since I can do the stuff I want outside that method