# AFNetworking, UITableView and Blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

So I was reading [How do I avoid capturing self in blocks when implementing an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api?rq=1) about how memory management works in regards to referencing self within a completion block and that got me thinking: will the following cause a retain cycle?

Pseudocode:

```
[AFnetworking requestGet:@"http://www.website.com" completionBlock:(^)(RequestObj* request, NSError* error){
      [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Ignoring syntax problems, does self.tableView cause a retain cycle? Is it necessary to do the following instead?

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
[AFnetworking requestGet:@"http://www.website.com" completionBlock:(^)(RequestObj* request, NSError* error){
      [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Or is there some sort of memory magic that AFNetworking does to prevent this?

---

Edit courtesy of Aaron Brager

Here you don't have a retain cycle. But if you did, in the completion block, you should convert weakSelf back into a strong reference so it won't get deallocated halfway through your completion block.

```
id strongSelf = weakSelf; 
[strongSelf.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Here you don't have a retain cycle.  But if you did, in the completion block, you should convert `weakSelf` back into a strong reference so it won't get deallocated halfway through your completion block.  (`id strongSelf = weakSelf; [strongSelf.tableView reloadData];`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A retain cycle occurs when two or more objects have strong references to each other.

In this case, the block will have a strong reference to `self`, but `self` doesn't have a strong reference to the block, so **you are fine here** and **no need to use** `weakSelf`.

The case when you'll have a retain cycle and need to break it by using the `weakSelf` is when the class has a strong reference to the block too like in the following example:

```
typedef void (^CompletionCallback)(RequestObj* request, NSError* error);

@interface SomeClass() {
    /// Strong reference to the block
    CompletionCallback completionBlock;
}
@end

@implementation SomeClass()

- (void)someMethod {
    completionBlock = ^(RequestObj* request, NSError* error) {
        /// Strong reference to the class
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    };

    [AFnetworking requestGet:@"http://www.website.com" completionBlock:completionBlock];
}

@end
```

In this example, both `completionBlock` and `self` have strong references to each other, and therefore you'll have a retain cycle here and need to break it.

Comment: It's people like you, Hejazi, that make me love stackoverflow. Thank you for being awesome.

Comment: Glad to be helpful. I updated the answer to give an example where you'll have a retain cycle.

Comment: Keep in mind the strong reference cycle may not be this straightforward.  For example, if your controller has a strong reference to an object, that object has a strong reference to a completion block, and then the completion block strongly references your controller, you'll still have a retain cycle, just with 3 objects instead of 2.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "when two or *more objects* have strong references to each other", but in our case the controller doesn't have a strong reference to an instance of `AFnetworking` for example.