# Why ARC is not deallocating memory after popViewController

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller

I'm pushing and popping ViewControllers in UINavigationController.

I'm tracking the memory consumption of my app.
While pushing the new viewController the memory consumption is increasing gradually, but when I'm popping the same ViewController using `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];` the memory consumption does not decrease but the constant.

That particular viewController can be pushed and popped by user many times which can lead the high memory consumption of app in RAM.

**What should I do to optimise my memory consumption?**

Comment: Does the viewController's `dealloc` get called after it is popped out.

Comment: @KudoCC I did not check it let me check it first

Comment: yes its being call because that object is not alive after popViewController call

Comment: So if `dealloc` calls, are you deallocating your resources in it? can you please show code for `dealloc` ?

Comment: i did not get you,should i need to implement dealloc method?,because i checked it in instrument that object is not alive.

Comment: you should implement dealloc method only if you have resources to release. If you don't release them, they will leak.

Comment: still i'm facing same issue here is my code -(void)dealloc
{
    NSArray *subViews = [self.view subviews];
    for (int i = 0; i <subViews.count; i++) {
        
        UIView *SubView=[subViews objectAtIndex:i] ;
        [SubView removeFromSuperview];
        SubView = Nil;
    }
}

Comment: If dealloc is being called then the problem isn't your view controller. What does instruments say the memory is being used for? Look up heapshot analysis. Are you looking at live bytes or total bytes?

Comment: @jrturton actually i'm using splitView controller,on didSelectRowAtIndex of masterViewController's table every time i'm creating a scrollView on DetailViewController and again that scrollView contains many subviews like label and textFields which is taking memory.Now when i'm going back i.e. popViewController then memory is not being release,what approach should i use.i stuck with it, even tried to manage memory without ARC i.e. -fno-objc-arc.but still i'm facing same issue.

Comment: Can you show the code where you select the table cell and when you go back?

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    
    //delete last scroll view if it is there
    if (self.scrollView) {
        [self.scrollView removeFromSuperview];
        self.scrollView = nil;
    }
    
    //call method to create View
    NSString *idString = [self.StepId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    [self createViewForTheSelectedCel:idString];
    
   
 
   }

Comment: CreateViewForSelectedCell creates scrollView add many labels and textField into that and makes that scroll view the subview of detailViewController.

Comment: is your viewController is referred as delegate in any other class and delegate have strong property?

Comment: no its not being  referred as delegate in any other class  @AkshayNalawade

Comment: Are you storing your navigation controllers any where? in an NSArray or NSDictionary or in any other collection. It seems to be you are maintaining a strong reference to them.

Comment: @NagaMalleshMaddali yes i'm storing it in an array i.e  self.splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.rootNav,self.detailNav,nil];

Comment: Since array will retain those view controllers, even though you pop them they wont be released. Try to remove view controller from array when you pop view controller from navigation controller. See if this reduces your memory consumption.

Comment: @walinaqvi did you tried my above suggestion?

Comment: Did you compile using the analyzer? That can turn up issues sometimes.

Comment: You should do a test. Disable the ARC for that particular view and keep eagle eye on memory and watch the behaviour if it is same or not

Answer (score 11):

When you dismiss a view controller (or pop it), it will be deallocated if you didn't make any strong pointers to it (that controller is retained by the navigation controller, or the presenting view controller, so you usually don't need to have a pointer to it when you create it and push or present it).

It will be be released if there are no other strong pointers to it

Comment: While correct, I don't think this is to the point. Despite the controller itself being deallocated there are times when memory usage does not decrease even with pops, like in the question.

Comment: Check out "abandoned memory" and how to find it. It's not the same as leaks. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/FindingAbandonedMemory/FindingAbandonedMemory.html

Comment: @Jonny, as i'm using navi controller too, but i got list of pages which are handled in it, which puts lots of load on stack, which occurs crash in the end, is there any way or technique to free the stack load

Answer (score 4):

Try to avoid using strong properties for IBOutlets.

Comment: Why? Weak outlets were relevant in iOS5, when views would get unloaded, but will not cause issues now.

Comment: You mean there wont be any difference if we declare an IBOutlet as a strong or weak property in ARC post iOS 5?

Comment: Interested in your point @jrturton, is this documented anywhere? Also, why would you use a strong property now instead of weak anyway?

Comment: @Jeff, Strong is the default, why do the extra? The point of weak properties was that they would be nilled out when the view was unloaded. The view doesn't get unloaded anymore, so there is no point. I don't know where this is documented.

Comment: Apple says "Outlets should generally be `weak`." [Here's the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html).

Comment: This is outdated now. Since iOS 7, am using IBOutlets as strong and it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

Consider reviewing whether you are referencing `self` in a block. If you do, you risk holding onto the UIViewController reference after you have popped it.

For a more in-depth review of why, check out this answer:
[How do I avoid capturing self in blocks when implementing an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api)

Answer (score 3):

If your app design allows the user to push and pop the same view controller over and over again, you may want to look at reusing the same view controller and just updating its contents each time it's pushed.

Instead of creating and destroying it over and over, create one, set up its contents and push, when it's popped, keep it around ready to be shown again. Next time it needs to be shown, update its contents and then push it again.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to say, that my last few days were spent on searching the web for my app memory problem. I was switching between 2 UIViewControllers. One of them had a scroll view which kept all subviews on it. It turned out that that UIVC loads a new scroll view without releasing the previous one. It took me several hours to realize it.

What I did was:

Looking for any kind of deadlocks inside the app, then searching for every variable that had a strong atributte and other desperate measures. But what really worked was:

```
 @IBAction func backBB(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    collectionView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.frontView.removeFromSuperview()
    eventsPhotos.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    symbolContainerView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.myScrollView.removeFromSuperview()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
}
```

I manually removed some views and contents. I've done it in "Back" button but you can do this in other methods like viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool).

Once I made this, my allocation chart in the developer instruments showed the memory allocation going up and down... And it was solved...

Comment: Although you solved it for your personal needs, that doesn't seem like a clean solution. I think there's some deeper key that needs to be figured out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get an error, when you try to pop the view controller because the navigation controller does not have a valid reference to the view controller, as it was released after you pushed it.

Answer (score 0):

Nil the popover on dismiss.

```
[menuPopup_ dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
menuPopup_ = nil;
```

Comment: The question doesn't refer to a popover.

Comment: Why is this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your viewcontroller (A) has no reference of any other viewcontroller (B) or any object it has. Incase it has then make sure that VC-B is not referencing back VC-A. If it has some reference back to VC-A then make it a weak property. Otherwise strong retain cycle will keep the VC in memory even if its popped.

- Another thing is to check wether theres any closure in your VC, check its body if it is referencing any property or method with self then make a [Capture list](https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/swift-capture-list-in-closures-e28282c71b95) to avoid retain cycle as "**Closures are Reference Types**"
- Check if theres any NSNotification observer you are not releasing
- Make a print call in deinit method to check wether its deallocated.

For further understanding on memory management:

- https://medium.com/mackmobile/avoiding-retain-cycles-in-swift-7b08d50fe3ef
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIy-qnGLpHU

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `unwind` segue instead of popping.