# Putting a viewcontroller in a navigation stack and then popping does not deallcoat memory and causes memory leakage

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, arkit, swift5

I am `navigating` from root view controller to the `second controller` which have `ARSCN` View now when I pop the controller from the stack it does not `deallocating` the memory and a huge memory leakage occurs when you move back and forward many times

Comment: check for strong variables and closures in vcs which must be deallocated

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398934/why-arc-is-not-deallocating-memory-after-popviewcontroller

Comment: there are no strong reference even an empty view controller increases memory after pushing and popping again and again ARC is not managing memory by itself I think there is a way to deinit your viewcontroller in hoping

Answer (score 0):

while popping a view controller from stack remove all the subview by 
-  view.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
and also deinit your resource like objects that are used in that view controller
-tested and solved by myself

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's going on without seeing your code but here are a few suggestions:

- If you are instantiating the second `UIViewController` if you are referencing it from the first `UIViewController` you need to make sure you're doing it in such a way you're not causing a reference cycle
- You should consider using `segue` instead of instantiation, you should only use instantiation if you have a specific reason to do so
- If you are using `segue`, you should use `unwind segue` instead of pop to return to the previous `UIViewController`