# Block is preventing dealloc although the block was copied

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, block, reference-counting

I believe I was following the rules but still a problem exists

My class **init** includes a block like this:

```
HTTPChunkReceiveBlock chunkBlock =  ^(id connection, NSData *data) {
    NSLog(@"Hi there!!");
};
```

and I am **passing this block** into an HttpConn obj which my class holds:

```
operation_ = [[HttpClient sharedClient] performChunkedRequest:url 
                                                 chunkHandler:chunkBlock];
```

Now for the problem: my object is never deallocated!!

The problem seems to be caused **because the HttpConn is keeping a pointer to the block**, but I want to mention two points:

1. The block is **not referring to self!**
2. The HttpConn class is keeping a **copy** of the block, like this:

> chunkBlock_ = [chunkBlock copy];
>   
>   Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

Extra info:
I have verified that if I'm freeing *operation_* then my object is deallocated fine:

```
reader.operation_ = nil;
reader = nil; //previous line allows 'dealloc' to be called
```

Now repeating the question: operation did not get a pointer of reader's *self*, it only holds a copy of the block which do not refer to self!

Comment: How do you know the block is the culprit? Have you actually verified using Instruments? I very much doubt it.

Comment: is your class acting as delegate, that would be a typical retain cause

Comment: To avoid a memory leak, you must always balance a Block_copy() with Block_release().

Comment: @Volker O_o Delegates are usually defined as `assign`, not `retain` to not create a cycle. But you're right, it might be something to check.

Comment: First of all, I'm amazed by the time it took you guys to respond, well appreciated!! Unfortunately I'm failing to use Instruments because it is causing me a segmentation fault in an unrelated, different place. This class is not used as a delegate. IMHO in ARC I shouldn't call Block_release. I have verified that if I am sending a 'nil' as the block, my object is deallocated ok

Comment: @ishahak: Alright, so the block _is_ the culprit. Does the block really look like the above, just an `NSLog`? If not, please post the real block.

Comment: Hi @DarkDust, I have nothing to hide, it is indeed only this :) (there was some real code but it was removed while trying to eliminate the root cause)

Comment: Hm, have you redefined `NSLog` to be a macro for better logging? (Command-click on NSLog to see its definition.) Other than that I fail to see how _anything_ might get captured by your block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, **I will answer my own question** so that others do not fall into the same problem. @DarkDust was actually correct. there was a tiny line which I was completely ignoring:

```
**retriesNumber++;**
```

It looks like an innocent sentence, but because *retriesNumber* is a member of the class, it is actually meaning

```
(INVISIBLE strong pointer to self)->retriesNumber
```

so the solution was to declare it as a property (versus a member ivar) so that we can use *self* to access it, and then write:

```
pSelf->retriesNumber++;
```

Thank you guys for your quick support, and I hope others will learn from it too!

Comment: The `foo->bar` syntax actually access the _instance variable_ `bar` on the object pointed to by `foo`, so you don't need a property here. The important point is to use a [weak reference to `self`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7854315/400056).

Comment: Hi @DarkDust, I have fixed my answer to make it clearer, saying INVISIBLE. The point here is that self is not appearing when referring to ivars. We must turn it into a property so that the weak self can be used

Comment: I was talking about `pSelf->retriesNumber++;`, this isn't accessing a property, it's accessing an instance variable.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the compiler will complain when using -> over a weak pointer which might become nil at some point. When using a property, you are sending a message, which is a safe operation